# Disabling a radio button does nothing

Tags: python, tkinter

I create my radio buttons and store them in a list as a class property:

```
for possible_answer in self.possible_answers:
        possible_answer = 
        R = ttk.Radiobutton(self,
                        text=possible_answer,
                        variable=var,
                        value=possible_answer,
                        command=lambda: self.set_chosen_answer(var.get()))
        self.radio_buttons.append(R)
```

and when the users selects any of the options, I want the radio buttons to become inactive or disabled. I tried doing this in the following manner:

```
    for radio_button in self.radio_buttons:
        radio_button.state = DISABLED
```

The code runs without problems, the only problem I have is that I am still able to click on other buttons after this - which I do not want.

Those two lines do get called as I have verified with printing each of radio button's state right after setting it and it prints "disabled" for each of them.

What am I doing wrong? I have read through documentation and similar posts but did not find anything useful. Did I misunderstand what the disabled state means? Should I do this differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state` is not an attribute of the widget object. It is a configuration option, which must be set by the `config` or `configure` method:

```
for radio_button in self.radio_buttons:
    radio_button.configure(state = DISABLED)
```